# Getting sane comparators with boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following `boost::variant` type

```
using MyType = boost::variant<int, double, char, std::string, bool>;
```

and I would like to be able to use this type in as natural way as possible, in particular I'd like to be able to use the comparison operators such that comparison of types that would compile, give then correct result, otherwise behaviour is undefined (or an exception is thrown). For example suppose I have

```
MyType x {2};       // int
MyType y {1.0};     // double
MyType z {"hello"}; // std::string
```

I'd like to be able to compare `x` with `y` in the same way as comparing `int {2}` and `double {1.0}`. `boost::variant` already defined `operator<` etc, so I can make this comparison, but the result is not as expected.

```
cout << (x < y) << endl; // 1
cout << (y < x) << endl; // 0
```

I can define the desired behaviour using a `boost::static_visitor`

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename R = MyType>
using enable_if_both_arithmetic = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, R>;

template <typename T, typename U, typename R = MyType>
using enable_if_not_both_arithmetic = std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && std::is_arithmetic<U>::value), R>;

class is_less_than : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    enable_if_both_arithmetic<T, U, bool> operator()(const T& lhs, const U& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    enable_if_not_both_arithmetic<T, U, bool> operator()(const T& lhs, const U& rhs) const
    {
        return false; // or could throw
    }
};
```

Which can be used like

```
cout << boost::apply_visitor(is_less_than(), x, y) << endl; // 0
```

but this is long and ugly. Is there someway I can 'overwrite' the `boost::variant::operator<` and use my own?

```
bool operator<(const VcfType& lhs, const VcfType& rhs)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor(is_less_than(), lhs, rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to define a subclass containing the `operator<` you need, either of  the `boost::variant<int, double, char, std::string, bool>` template instantiation (probably simpler) or of the  `boost::variant<>` template (if you have other cases to cover).